# Jexl toLowerCase() and replace()

Tags: javascript, npm, jexl

I am using [jexl.eval](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jexl#jexleval-string-expression---context-) function to evaluate a value as follows-

```
jexl.eval("dataset[0].data['Entity Name'].toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '_')",data);
```

dataset[0].data['Entity Name'] is always a string and is never null,
there seems to be some error in jexl.eval, It returns empty string always

I wanted to confirm if toLowerCase() and replace() are supported or not? whether there is some issue in my syntax?

[jexl playground](https://czosel.github.io/jexl-playground/#/?context=%7B%0A%20%20%22dataset%22%3A%20%5B%0A%0A%7B%0A%20%20%22data%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22Entity%20Label%22%3A%20%22Example%20Entity%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22CovenantType%22%3A%5B%7Bname%3A%20%27Manual%27%7D%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22RuleId%22%3A%22Helo%22%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%7D%0A%20%20%5D%2C%0A%22entityName%22%3A%22Entity%20Name%22%0A%7D&input=dataset.data%5B%27CovenantType%27%5D.name%3D%3D%27Calculated%27%20%3F%20entityName%20%7C%20lower%20%7C%20replace(%27%20%27%2C%20%27_%27)%20%3A%20%22%22%0A%0A%0A&transforms=%7B%0A%20%20%22lower%22%3A%20(val)%20%3D%3E%20val.toLowerCase()%2C%0A%20%20%22replace%22%3A%20(val%2C%20search%2C%20replacement)%20%3D%3E%20val.replace(new%20RegExp(search%2C%20%27g%27)%2C%20replacement)%0A%7D) for next query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`toLowerCase()` and `replace` are supported methods for string manipulation but you're using the wrong syntax which may be one of the reasons for unwanted output.

In JEXL, you can use the `|` (pipe) operator to chain *[transformations](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jexl#transforms)* on a value. So, to properly use them, you need to define thee transform functions(for `toLowerCase` and `replace`) before using them in your JEXL expression. Something like:

```js
jexl.eval("dataset[0].data['Entity Name'] | lower | replace(' ', '_')", data);

// Tranformations 
jexl.addTransform('lower', (val) => val.toLowerCase());
jexl.addTransform('replace', (val, search, replacement) => val.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement));
```

*[JEXL playground](https://t.ly/NoKs9)*

Comment: I have a new query now, What if I want to evaluate conditional statements through eval, I have added the scenario in jexl playground (you can check my question I have updated the link), can you check?

Comment: @meg sure will take a look in some time. Actually, I am away for an hour or so. Will take a look once I come back

Comment: @meg, you syntax was wrong. Check **[here](https://t.ly/TIykB)**